# Вставка переменной в значение переменной в JS

Tags: javascript

Как вставить в пропущенные места этой переменной:

```
var madlib = 'The Intro to JavaScript course is __________. James and Julia are so __________. I cannot wait to work through the rest of this __________ content';
```

эти переменные:

```
var adjective1 = 'amazing';
var adjective2 = 'fun';
var adjective3 = 'entertaining';
```

Comment: это задание по английскому, а не по `js`:D

Comment: Не важны значения переменных а главное как реализовать. И если хотите можете сделать значения по своему желанию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var adjective1 = 'amazing';
var adjective2 = 'fun';
var adjective3 = 'entertaining';

var madlib = `
  The Intro to JavaScript course is ${adjective2}. 
  James and Julia are so ${adjective1}. 
  I cannot wait to work through the rest of this ${adjective3} content.
\n`;

console.log(madlib);
```